# C++ function used to work, now returning 0xfdfdfdfd

Tags: c++, pointers, inline-functions

I have some code I wrote a few years ago.  It has been working fine, but after a recent rebuild with some new, unrelated code elsewhere, it is no longer working.  This is the code:

```
//myobject.h
...
inline  CMapStringToOb* GetMap(void)    {return (m_lpcMap);};
...
```

The above is accessed from the main app like so:

```
//otherclass.cpp
...
CMapStringToOb* lpcMap = static_cast<CMyObject*>(m_lpcBaseClass)->GetMap();
...
```

Like I said, this WAS working for a long time, but it's just decided to start failing as of our most recent build.  I have debugged into this, and I am able to see that, in the code where the pointer is set, it is correctly setting the memory address to an actual value.  I have even been able to step into the set function, write down the memory address, then move to this function, let it get 0xfdfdfdfd, and then manually get the memory address in the debugger.  This causes the code to work.  Now, from what I've read, 0xfdfdfdfd means guarding bytes or "no man's land", but I don't really understand what the implications of that are.  Supposedly it also means an off by one error, but I don't understand how that could happen, if the code was working before.

Comment: Sounds like you've entered the wonderful land of undefined behavior. If you have access to Purify you can use that to help. Alternately if you can compile a small part of the code on Linux valgrind would be your friend.

Comment: Check for a change in the set function where a local variable with the same name is being set instead of the member variable. I have seen that bug a few times.

Comment: Maybe the object is OK, but the pointer to it gets damaged - did you check that? Maybe the address is ok but the object gets destroyed? Can't you just set a watchpoint on &m_lpcMap and stop execution whenever it's overwritten?

Comment: "after a recent rebuild with some new, unrelated code elsewhere, it is no longer working"... sounds like it was related after all.

Comment: How do you know that `m_lpcBaseClass` actually points to an instance of `CMyObject`? If the base class is polymorphic, then you could use `dynamic_cast` to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenarios where "magic" happens almost always come back to memory corruption. I suspect that somewhere else in your code you've modified memory incorrectly, and it's resulting in this peculiar behavior. Try testing some different ways of entering this part of the code. Is the behavior consistent?

This could also be caused by an incorrectly built binary. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: I appreciate the input from everyone here, but this answer probably comes the closest to fixing the issue.  It turns out, another team's suite of projects, which ours are dependent on, had not been built correctly, so we had a mishmash of different library versions getting built into our code.  Finally getting all the references and dependencies rebuilt and matching solved this and a couple other problems.  Thanks again to all who commented and answered.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming from the Hungarian notation that you're using Visual Studio. Since you do know the address that holds the map pointer, start your program in the debugger and set a data breakpoint when that map pointer changes (the memory holding the map pointer, not the map pointed to). Then you'll find out *exactly* when it's getting overwritten.

Comment: This was a good answer, and one of the major clues I found was that I could not step into some functions, as the debug information was not being built into my debug versions from the other libraries.

Answer (score 3):

`0xfdfdfdfd` typically implies that you have accessed memory that you weren't supposed to.

- There is a **good chance** the memory was allocated and subsequently freed.  So you're using freed memory.
- `static_cast` can modify a pointer and you have an explicit cast to `CMyObject` and an implicit cast to `CMapStringToOb`.  Check the validity of the pointer directly returned from `GetMap()`.